# Реализация интерфейсов с одинаковым методом в java

Tags: java, интерфейс

Я сейчас изучаю Java и у меня возник вопрос насчет интерфейсов.

С 8-ой версии в Java появилась возможность добавлять в интерфейс реализацию метода с обозначением default. При этом так как есть множественная реализация интерфейсов, то есть возможность реализовать несколько интерфейсов с одинаковыми именами некоторых методов, но с разной их default-реализацией.

Не приводит ли такое решение к тем же проблемам, что и множественное наследование? И почему тогда просто не добавили множественной наследование классов? Не совсем понимаю это. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Думаю, [тут](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/818-metodih-po-umolchaniju-v-java-8-chto-mogut-i-chego-ne-mogut) есть ответ на Ваш вопрос.